# why would identical mongo query take much longer via aggregation than via find?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

so, i have 10M people documents. this query:

```
db.getCollection('people').find({'address.zip': '87447'}).sort({'name.last': -1}).limit(3)
```

returns in < 20ms

this query:

```
db.getCollection('people').aggregate([{$match: {'address.zip': '87447'}},{$sort: {'name.last': -1}}, {$limit: 3}])
```

returns in > 20s

i have indexes on `address.zip` and `name.last`

there are only about 100 or so documents that meet the `$match` criteria...

baffled...

here are explains:

**find**

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "people.people",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "address.zip" : {
                "$eq" : "87447"
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "name.last" : -1.0
            },
            "limitAmount" : 3,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "address.zip" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "address.zip_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "address.zip" : []
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "address.zip" : [
                                "[\"87447\", \"87447\"]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "LIMIT",
                "limitAmount" : 3,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "address.zip" : {
                            "$eq" : "87447"
                        }
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "name.last" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "name.last_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "name.last" : []
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "backward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "name.last" : [
                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "00caaca2f8e7",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.7.2",
        "gitVersion" : "ca0a855dfc0f479d85b76a640b12a259c0547310"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

**aggregate**

```
{
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "address.zip" : "87447"
                },
                "sort" : {
                    "name.last" : -1
                },
                "limit" : NumberLong(3),
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "people.people",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "address.zip" : {
                            "$eq" : "87447"
                        }
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "address.zip" : {
                                "$eq" : "87447"
                            }
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "name.last" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "name.last_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "name.last" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "backward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "name.last" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

any suggestions on where the issue lies or how to troubleshoot?

Comment: did you compare the execution times having the compound index suggested by @Asya Kamsky

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate and find use different query plans because currently aggregation explicitly requests that a non-blocking plan (i.e. one that can use an index to provide the sort order) is used.

There is a Jira ticket (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7568) that's tracking the work to improve this, as the query plan that sorts in memory can be faster if a small number of documents match the query.

However, in all cases having a compound index that satisfies the filter and sort clauses would perform best for both find and aggregate.  In your case that would be an index on `{"address.zip":1, "name.last":1}`

Note that as of 3.6 you can also [provide `hint` to aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate) to specify which index you want used.

Comment: thanks @asya, in my case, i was going for an ad-hoc query setup where i would place solo indices on fields available for either filter or sort and let the optimizer do it's thing. compound-indices would lead to an exponential number of combinations if i went for that. the hint thing might help at times, but i wouldn't know as much as the optimizer. i like the suggestions for improvement called out in SERVER-7568 tho, guess i'll keep an eye on that. thx!